# Django how to do model1.model2_set.all() in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm building a website and I have two models, let's call them Model1 and Model2, with Model2 having a foreignKey attribute pointing towards Model1. I have a template in which I have access to the list of all entry in the Model1 table of the database. What I want is doing a for loop over all the entries model2 associated to a specific entry model1.
In a view, I could do : `for model2 in model1.model2_set.all():` but how can I do that in a template ?
I've tried `{% for model2 in model1.model2_set.all %}` but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : 
models.py

```
class Plat(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)
    allergenes = models.TextField(null = True)
    prix = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Prix par portion")
    chef = models.ForeignKey('inscription.Chef', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_prep = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date et heure de préparation")
    nb_portions = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre de portions disponibles")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = "photos_plat/")
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Plat"
        ordering = ['date_prep']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre


class Commande(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    plat = models.ForeignKey('Plat', on_delete = models.CASCADE) # models.PROTECT pour pas supprimer, models.CASCADE pour supprimer.
    nb_portions = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre de portions")
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date de commande")
    livraison = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    adresse_livraison = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Adresse de livraison", blank = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Commande"
        ordering = ['date']
```

Model1 is Plat and Model2 is Commande

views.py

```
def mes_plats(request):
    return render(request, 'actualites/mes_plats.html', {'my_meals': Plat.objects.filter(chef=request.user.useradvanced.chef, date_prep__gte = date.today())})
```

mes_plats.html

```
{% for plat in my_meals %}
   {% if plat.is_ordered %}
      <ul>
      {% for commande in plat.commande_set.all %}
          <li> {{ commande.user.useradvanced }} : {{ commande.nb_portions}} portions.</li>
      </ul>
   {% else %}
      Ce plat n'a pas encore été commandé par un utilisateur.
   {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please include your model code. Did you specify a `related_name` in your FK field?

Comment: I added it in the edit section of the post

Comment: So just to verify, you have `{% for cmm in plat.commande_set.all %}` (with `plat` being a _single_ `Plat` object) and it's not working?

Comment: Yes, I added the whole code in the edit section

Comment: "doesn't work" is a totally useless description of a problem. Please edit your post to explain __how__ it "doesn't work", with all relevant details.

Comment: Problem solved sorry, I made a stupid mistake and didn't close my for loop....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pass your `model1` instance to the template through context like this:

```
   def your_view(request,pk):
      model1_instance = YourModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
      return render(request,'your_template',{'model1':model1_instance})
```

Now in your template this `{% for model2 in model1.model2_set.all %}` should work.

EDIT:
If you have passed the queryset to the template you can do like this

```
{% for obj1 in your_model1_queryset %}
   {% for obj2 in obj1.model2_set.all %}
      ...
   {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to do the for loop for all model1 instances in the database. So I pass ```model1.objects.all()``` to the template but I can't pass each specific instance

Comment: Yes that's what I do (see my code in the EDIT section of the post) but that doesn't work.. I get this error ```TemplateSyntaxError at /mes-plats
Invalid block tag on line 31: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?```. It seems like there is nothing in the for loop, but it's impossible I have verified and the loop should not be empty

Comment: @JulienMertz that means you haven't closed your forloop tag proeprly